# py2app and pandas giving RecursionError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, py2app

I am trying to build a simple app using py2app and pandas, below are my app.py and setup.py files used to create the app using `python setup.py py2app`

app.py

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([0, 1, 2])
print(x)
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['app.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
'argv_emulation': True
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

Now on trying to build this code i get an error,

```
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 615, in visit_ImportFrom
    self._process_import(node.module or '', _ast_names(node.names), level)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 600, in _process_import
    fromlist=False,
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1218, in _safe_import_hook
    mods = self.import_hook(name, caller, level=level, attr=attr)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 949, in import_hook
    m = self._load_tail(q, tail)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1054, in _load_tail
    result = self._import_module(head, mname, result)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1130, in _import_module
    m = self._load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1203, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(co, m)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1276, in _scan_code
    self._scan_ast(co, m)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1285, in _scan_ast
    visitor.visit(co)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 245, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 253, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 245, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 253, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 245, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 253, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 245, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 255, in generic_visit
    self.visit(value)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 245, in visit
    return visitor(node)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Version info:

- python 3.5.1 from Anaconda
- py2app 0.9
- pandas 0.17.1
- Mac 10.11 (el capitan)

Please check this example out and help me figure out a solution.

Edit:
tried on python 2.7 and got the same error.